# Kibana Error: Kibana server is not ready yet

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana

i have installed Elasticsearch 8 and Kibana 8 in Ubuntu and all configs are right.
elasticsearch url works correctly by loading url: `http://localhost:9200` :

```
{
  "name": "node-1",
  "cluster_name": "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid": "0smulADyTDG3jNeg3fwMGg",
  "version": {
    "number": "8.4.3",
    "build_flavor": "default",
    "build_type": "deb",
    "build_hash": "42f05b9372a9a4a470db3b52817899b99a76ee73",
    "build_date": "2022-10-04T07:17:24.662462378Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "9.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but i have `(Kibana server is not ready yet)` error by loading kibana url: `http://localhost:5601`

my `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: localhost
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Readiness ----------------------------------
#
# Enable an unauthenticated TCP readiness endpoint on localhost
#
#readiness.port: 9399
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false
```

and my `kibana.yml`:

```
# For more configuration options see the configuration guide for Kibana in
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html

# =================== System: Kibana Server ===================
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "localhost"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# Defaults to `false`.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# Specifies the public URL at which Kibana is available for end users. If
# `server.basePath` is configured this URL should end with the same basePath.
#server.publicBaseUrl: ""

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayload: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name. This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# =================== System: Kibana Server (Optional) ===================
# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# =================== System: Elasticsearch ===================
# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Kibana can also authenticate to Elasticsearch via "service account tokens".
# Service account tokens are Bearer style tokens that replace the traditional username/password based configuration.
# Use this token instead of a username/password.
# elasticsearch.serviceAccountToken: "my_token"

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# The maximum number of sockets that can be used for communications with elasticsearch.
# Defaults to `Infinity`.
#elasticsearch.maxSockets: 1024

# Specifies whether Kibana should use compression for communications with elasticsearch
# Defaults to `false`.
#elasticsearch.compression: false

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# =================== System: Elasticsearch (Optional) ===================
# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# =================== System: Logging ===================
# Set the value of this setting to off to suppress all logging output, or to debug to log everything. Defaults to 'info'
#logging.root.level: debug

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
logging:
  appenders:
    file:
      type: file
      fileName: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log
      layout:
        type: json
  root:
    appenders:
      - default
      - file
#  layout:
#    type: json

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch.
#logging.loggers:
#  - name: elasticsearch.query
#    level: debug

# Logs http responses.
#logging.loggers:
#  - name: http.server.response
#    level: debug

# Logs system usage information.
#logging.loggers:
#  - name: metrics.ops
#    level: debug

# =================== System: Other ===================
# The path where Kibana stores persistent data not saved in Elasticsearch. Defaults to data
#path.data: data

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
pid.file: /run/kibana/kibana.pid

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000ms.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English (default) "en", Chinese "zh-CN", Japanese "ja-JP", French "fr-FR".
#i18n.locale: "en"

# =================== Frequently used (Optional)===================

# =================== Saved Objects: Migrations ===================
# Saved object migrations run at startup. If you run into migration-related issues, you might need to adjust these settings.

# The number of documents migrated at a time.
# If Kibana can't start up or upgrade due to an Elasticsearch `circuit_breaking_exception`,
# use a smaller batchSize value to reduce the memory pressure. Defaults to 1000 objects per batch.
#migrations.batchSize: 1000

# The maximum payload size for indexing batches of upgraded saved objects.
# To avoid migrations failing due to a 413 Request Entity Too Large response from Elasticsearch.
# This value should be lower than or equal to your Elasticsearch cluster’s `http.max_content_length`
# configuration option. Default: 100mb
#migrations.maxBatchSizeBytes: 100mb

# The number of times to retry temporary migration failures. Increase the setting
# if migrations fail frequently with a message such as `Unable to complete the [...] step after
# 15 attempts, terminating`. Defaults to 15
#migrations.retryAttempts: 15

# =================== Search Autocomplete ===================
# Time in milliseconds to wait for autocomplete suggestions from Elasticsearch.
# This value must be a whole number greater than zero. Defaults to 1000ms
#unifiedSearch.autocomplete.valueSuggestions.timeout: 1000

# Maximum number of documents loaded by each shard to generate autocomplete suggestions.
# This value must be a whole number greater than zero. Defaults to 100_000
#unifiedSearch.autocomplete.valueSuggestions.terminateAfter: 100000
```

Kibana Log:

```
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:20.411+03:30","message":"Kibana process configured with roles: [background_tasks, ui]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"node"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"c6ea68fa3419d0f3b516d7a5384405e5"},"transaction":{"id":"7541ff0f36063377"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.183+03:30","message":"http server running at http://localhost:5601","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"http.server.Preboot"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"c6ea68fa3419d0f3b516d7a5384405e5"},"transaction":{"id":"7541ff0f36063377"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.225+03:30","message":"Setting up [1] plugins: [interactiveSetup]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins-system.preboot"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"c6ea68fa3419d0f3b516d7a5384405e5"},"transaction":{"id":"7541ff0f36063377"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.228+03:30","message":"\"interactiveSetup\" plugin is holding setup: Validating Elasticsearch connection configuration…","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"preboot"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"c6ea68fa3419d0f3b516d7a5384405e5"},"transaction":{"id":"7541ff0f36063377"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.264+03:30","message":"Holding setup until preboot stage is completed.","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"root"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"c6ea68fa3419d0f3b516d7a5384405e5"},"transaction":{"id":"7541ff0f36063377"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.316+03:30","message":"The default mechanism for Reporting privileges will work differently in future versions, which will affect the behavior of this cluster. Set \"xpack.reporting.roles.enabled\" to \"false\" to adopt the future behavior before upgrading.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"config.deprecation"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.534+03:30","message":"Setting up [121] plugins: [translations,monitoringCollection,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,features,mapsEms,licenseApiGuard,usageCollection,taskManager,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,share,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,screenshotMode,banners,newsfeed,fieldFormats,expressions,dataViews,charts,esUiShared,customIntegrations,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,advancedSettings,spaces,security,lists,encryptedSavedObjects,cloud,snapshotRestore,screenshotting,telemetry,licenseManagement,eventLog,actions,console,bfetch,data,watcher,reporting,fileUpload,ingestPipelines,alerting,unifiedSearch,savedObjects,graph,savedObjectsTagging,savedObjectsManagement,presentationUtil,expressionShape,expressionRevealImage,expressionRepeatImage,expressionMetric,expressionImage,controls,eventAnnotation,dataViewFieldEditor,triggersActionsUi,transform,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,discover,fleet,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,cloudSecurityPosture,discoverEnhanced,aiops,visualizations,canvas,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypeMetric,visTypeHeatmap,visTypeMarkdown,dashboard,dashboardEnhanced,expressionXY,expressionTagcloud,expressionPartitionVis,visTypePie,expressionMetricVis,expressionLegacyMetricVis,expressionHeatmap,expressionGauge,lens,osquery,maps,dataVisualizer,ml,cases,timelines,sessionView,kubernetesSecurity,securitySolution,visTypeGauge,sharedUX,observability,synthetics,infra,upgradeAssistant,monitoring,logstash,enterpriseSearch,apm,dataViewManagement]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins-system.standard"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.557+03:30","message":"TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: a8d17e19-ba6f-4036-a256-02c589aa4248","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins.taskManager"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.650+03:30","message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.security.config"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.651+03:30","message":"Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.security.config"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.683+03:30","message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.security.config"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.683+03:30","message":"Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.security.config"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.692+03:30","message":"Saved objects encryption key is not set. This will severely limit Kibana functionality. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.encryptedSavedObjects"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.711+03:30","message":"APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.actions"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.823+03:30","message":"Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.reporting.config"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.830+03:30","message":"APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.","log":{"level":"WARN","logger":"plugins.alerting"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.884+03:30","message":"Installing common resources shared between all indices","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins.ruleRegistry"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:30.928+03:30","message":"Registered task successfully [Task: cloud_security_posture-stats_task]","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins.cloudSecurityPosture"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:31.608+03:30","message":"Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, and is supported for Linux Ubuntu 20.04 OS. Automatically enabling Chromium sandbox.","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins.screenshotting.config"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:31.656+03:30","message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]","log":{"level":"ERROR","logger":"elasticsearch-service"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
{"service":{"node":{"roles":["background_tasks","ui"]}},"ecs":{"version":"8.4.0"},"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:59:32.236+03:30","message":"Browser executable: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/screenshotting/chromium/headless_shell-linux_x64/headless_shell","log":{"level":"INFO","logger":"plugins.screenshotting.chromium"},"process":{"pid":19085},"trace":{"id":"16dd4b7458247a11c4ea203116264222"},"transaction":{"id":"c4c9d814a9603b7d"}}
```

Comment: can you share your Kibana log please

Comment: @warkolm yes. I added the log in the edit to my question

Comment: you should check this `[security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request`

Comment: @K1-Aria did you solve the issue ? i'm facing the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncomment the following line in kibana.yml

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

Comment: i did it. but still not working